# Access is denied for the user assigned to group instead of direct assignment to app

Tags: asp.net-core, okta

I have an application defined in Okta. Both app and users are assigned to the group, yet when user tries to login he gets access denied: `Message contains error: 'access_denied', error_description: 'User is not assigned to the client application.'`

When user is assigned to app directly, then it can sign in. But should not it work with the group?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should work regardless. Are you able to see the application in the list of assigned for your user, when you check in Okta UI? Maybe the group is large, so it takes time, when you assign a large group to the app. Or when a group is assigned to a lot of apps. But in the end you should be able to see the app in question in the list of apps. If it's the case, then something wrong is happening here. Might worth open a ticket with Okta Support. If you don't see the app there, then you do something wrong

Comment: No, the group is small - 6 users. I see my user belongs to the group, the group itself has the app assigned, but I do not see it in the list of assigned apps for my user.

Comment: is the app active? is the app assigned to the group 100%? can you open your app and check assignments -> groups?

Comment: Yes, it's active, I opened support case in Okta.

Comment: @PavelVoronin any update on this? We have exactly same issue

Comment: @Fseee The fun fact that it works for non local urls, and fails when I test it locally. I opened the support case, but they do not see any reasons for the issue. Do it as well, so they feel more pressure to investigate.

Comment: Did you guys try to unassigns the group from the app and then assign back?

Comment: @PhilippGrigoryev yes, that trick did the job